# "OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address" OS X python Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am currently coding a program that creates a socket in python and allows the owner to execute commands on the user machine. This is my code:

```py
import socket
import subprocess, os

print("#####################")
print("#   I wonder what   #")
print("# this program does #")
print("#                   #")
print("#                   #")
print("#                   #")
print("#                   #")
print("#####################")

host = input("What host would you like to use? ")
port = int(input("What port would you like to use? "))
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
server_socket.bind((host, port))

server_socket.listen(5)  
print("\n[*] Listening on port " +str(port)+ ", waiting for connections.")

client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " +client_ip+ " connected.\n")
 
while True:
    try:
        command = input(client_ip+ "> ")
        if(len(command.split()) != 0):
            client_socket.send(command)
        else:
            continue
    except(EOFError):
        print("ERROR INPUT NOT FOUND. Please type 'help' to get a list of commands.\n")
        continue
 
    if(command == "quit"):
        break
 
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(data + "\n")
 
    client_socket.close()
```

It is working fine on Windows 10 , but on my Mac it says this error:

> OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

Any fix?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What input values are you actually providing the program for it to `bind()` its listening to?  Are you, by chance, trying to bind to a reserved system port < 1024?  Windows is less strict about that than other platforms are. Only admins can use those ports.

Comment: Ok, I only tested the ports 12345 and 1234 I will try some others. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: What about the `host`? What value are you providing for that? It is hard to tell you why `bind()` fails when you don't show what you are asking it to bind to exactly. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The program uses user input to assign the port and host such as: host = input("What host would you like to use? ") and then port = int(input("What port would you like to use? ")) and to bind them server_socket.bind((host, port)). I tried a bunch of ports and they didn't work. Same error. My firewall is also off so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: The host is the user IP address in which they are hosting the socket on

Comment: "*The program uses user input to assign the port and host*" - I'm aware of that. I'm asking what SPECIFICALLY is being entered for those values when the error occurs. "*The host is the user IP address in which they are hosting the socket on*" - and how do you know a *valid* IP belonging to the local machine is being entered? You can only `bind()` to an IP that belongs to the same machine the program is running on.  Also, have you tried using `netstat` or equivilent to make sure the `IP:port` pair being requested is not already in use by another program?

Comment: Nevermind it was the host haha thank you, man! I am pretty dumb lol I was using my windows IP as the host haha thanks!